# pandas data manipulation in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a data frame `df` with columns `ID` and `N1`, I would like to calculate column `N2`, with logic first value should be equal to N1 for each ID and the next value is 0.888/0.999 and so on. And similarly for next ID. Can we do this WITHOUT using for loop in `pandas`

```
ID  N1  N2
1111    0.999   0.999
1111    0.888   0.888888889
1111    0.777   0.875
1111    0.666   0.857142857
1111    0.555   0.833333333
1111    0.444   0.8
1111    0.333   0.75
2222    0.998   0.998
2222    0.887   0.888777555
2222    0.776   0.874859076
2222    0.665   0.856958763
2222    0.554   0.833082707
2222    0.443   0.799638989
2222    0.332   0.749435666
2222    0.221   0.665662651
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `groupby()`, `transform()` and `shift()` then `fillna(1)` to allow for that first value.

```
df['N2'] = df.groupby("ID")['N1'].transform(lambda x: x/x.shift(1).fillna(1))
df

      ID     N1        N2
0   1111  0.999  0.999000
1   1111  0.888  0.888889
2   1111  0.777  0.875000
3   1111  0.666  0.857143
4   1111  0.555  0.833333
5   1111  0.444  0.800000
6   1111  0.333  0.750000
7   2222  0.998  0.998000
8   2222  0.887  0.888778
9   2222  0.776  0.874859
10  2222  0.665  0.856959
11  2222  0.554  0.833083
12  2222  0.443  0.799639
13  2222  0.332  0.749436
14  2222  0.221  0.665663
```

Comment: This one takes less time when you deal with large data set. So accepted this answer.

Comment: This is very slow on large data frame, is there any NumPy solution, which can be faster

Comment: @user2684128  You might repost the problem with an emphasis on using NumPy.

Answer (score 5):

This is `1` plus the percentage change

```
df.assign(N2=df.groupby('ID').N1.pct_change().add(1).fillna(df.N1))

      ID     N1        N2
0   1111  0.999  0.999000
1   1111  0.888  0.888889
2   1111  0.777  0.875000
3   1111  0.666  0.857143
4   1111  0.555  0.833333
5   1111  0.444  0.800000
6   1111  0.333  0.750000
7   2222  0.998  0.998000
8   2222  0.887  0.888778
9   2222  0.776  0.874859
10  2222  0.665  0.856959
11  2222  0.554  0.833083
12  2222  0.443  0.799639
13  2222  0.332  0.749436
14  2222  0.221  0.665663
```

Comment: `1 plus the percentage change` - very clever !

Comment: @MaxU wha't clever is you / Jeff in [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41784854/2336654) then what I did with that [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43239617/2336654)

Comment: thanks for the link - i didn't see your brilliant answer ;-)

Comment: @MaxU thx.. I was proud of that one, will save it for later :-)